# How do I make solver work over a set of points?

Tags: python, iteration

I have a Jacobi iterative solver made in Python, that works on a matrix of size nxn. However only the k = 1, 0, -1 diagonals have non-zero values so the solver wastes substantial amounts time and computational effort. I want the solver to only work on the non-zero elements, which are linked in a +. like below
0 ,     (i,j+1), 0
(i-1,j), (i,j), (i+1,j)
0,   (i,j-1),  0

First I implemented the condition M[i,j]!=0, so that the iterative solver won't work on the elements that have a value of zero. Afterwards, I tried various approaches to implement the grid above such as making the grid above a condition and provided a flat plane of zeroes. Whilst it would be easier to deal single values, the calculations require a set of values to make it more time-efficient.
However I will attach the code relevant code below.

```
x = 1
y = 1
Nx = 20
Ny = 20
Px = Nx + 1
Py = Ny + 1
hx = x/Nx
hy = y/Ny
sol_len = (Px)*(Py)
m = np.zeros([ sol_len,sol_len])
h = np.zeros([sol_len])
n=len(h)
T=np.zeros(n)
T[:] = 1 # setting up intial guess
### The Jacobi part
for k in range(1000): # defining number of iterations  
  for i in range(n): # defining range of i from 0 to n
     xapprox  =  h[i] 
     for j in range(0,i):# works along each horizontal grid marking
         if m[i,j]!=0:#excludes elements that are 0
         #print('J ',j)
           xapprox = xapprox - m[i,j]*T[j]
     for j in range(i+1,n):
         if m[i,j]!=0:#excludes elements that are 0
         #print('J ',j)
           xapprox = xapprox - m[i,j]*T[j]
     if abs(m[i,i])>0:     
       T[i] = (1/m[i,i])*xapprox
```

Comment: Is it tridiagonal matrix?

Comment: you can exploit the sparse nature of the matrix `m` to speed up the computation. Since you know that only the diagonals `k = 1, 0, -1` have non-zero values, you don't need to check all elements. You can modify the inner loop to consider only the elements in those diagonals.

Comment: Mamed, it is a tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: You need to eliminate needless operations on zero elements and make sure that accurate iterative updates done. Give me some time I will paste code. Need to test

Comment: I am aware of the fact that my matrix is sparse Obaskly, I tried to exploit that fact for two to three days and tried to modify the inner loop but I have acheived no progress in making my solver run much faster.

Comment: Note that grid position = j*Px + i

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe.

```
import numpy as np

x = 1
y = 1
Nx = 20
Ny = 20
Px = Nx + 1
Py = Ny + 1
hx = x/Nx
hy = y/Ny
n = (Px)*(Py)
diag = np.zeros(n)  # this is our main diagonal
upper_diag = np.zeros(n - 1)  # up part diagonal
lower_diag = np.zeros(n - 1)  # low par diagonal
h = np.zeros(n)
T = np.ones(n)  # we need to guess here

# then fill diag, upper_diag, lower_diag with your own values

for k in range(1000):    
    T_new = np.copy(T)  
    for i in range(1, n-1):  
        xapprox = h[i] - upper_diag[i-1]*T[i-1] - lower_diag[i]*T[i+1]
        if abs(diag[i]) > 0:     
            T_new[i] = xapprox / diag[i]
    T = T_new
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, whilst your code does drastically speed up the solver the results that is seen is inaccurate. But I will tweak the code to account for this.

Comment: What exactly is inaccurate? Maybe I can fix it. Or maybe you can choose my answer as right answer if it helped

Comment: Whilst the code works for an empty matrix 'm', I can't get the results to be accurate enough for my coniditions on the matrix.

Comment: Mamed, I've edited my initial post if it helps.